# How can I structure nHibernate QueryOver where (X AND Y) OR (null AND null)

Tags: linq, nhibernate, queryover

In SQL ease:

```
where (Id1 = @iX and Id2 = @iY) OR (id1 is null AND Id2 is null)
```

In (sudo/failed) nHibernate:

```
where (c => c.Id1 == iX AND c.Id2 == iY) OR (c => c.Id1 == null AND c.Id2 == null)
```

All helpful suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

using criteria:

```
        var r = ses.CreateCriteria<myT>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Or(
                Restrictions.And(Restrictions.Where<myT>((c) => c.Id1 == iX)
                    , Restrictions.Where<myT>((c) => c.Id2 == iY)
                )
                , Restrictions.And(Restrictions.Where<myT>((c) => c.Id1 == null)
                    , Restrictions.Where<myT>((c) => c.Id2 == null)
                )
            ))
            .List<myT>();
```

Nets a reasonable:

```
WHERE ((this_.Id1 = @p0 and this_.Id2 = @p1) or (this_.Id1 is null and this_.Id2 is null))
```

where @p0 = @iX and @p1 = @iY